# tsc --watch rebuilds project but not including changes in node_modules

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

We develop a Typescript express app and a library.
We serve locally on a firebase function.
We manually link the output of the library into the node_modules of the app.

Running the **app**: `tsc --watch & firebase serve --only functions`

Compiling the **library**: `tsc --watch`

---

If we change something in the **app**:

- **app** rebuild is triggered
- changes appear in runtime

---

If we change something in the **library**:

- **library** rebuild is triggered
- app node_modules link is updated
- **app** rebuilds as expected
- changes **does not** appear in runtime..
- kill app process
- relaunch app
- changes appear in runtime

---

app package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-backend",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Backend hello world"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "TacB0sS",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "launch": "tsc --watch & firebase serve --only functions",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@app/app-shared": "0.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^7.2.3",
    "firebase-admin": "8.9.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "use-strict": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.3",
    "@types/saml2-js": "^1.6.8",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@consts": "dist/consts",
    "@modules": "dist/modules"
  }
}
```

library: package.json

```
{
  "name": "@app/app-shared",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "app-shared",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "TacB0sS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --watch",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

---

So another thing I've learned is that if I call process.exit() after the library has changed, the next instance of the function would have the updated code from the library...

How can we make the rebuild to use our changes in the library without the need to relaunch or kill my function process?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail the relationship between the app and the library.  It might be helpful to see your package.json to understand how the app is put together and how exactly the library participates in that.

Comment: There is really nothing special about it.. I manage the linking manually from the terminal but sure.. few moments

Comment: I suggest putting enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.  Personally, I don't know how I would go about building a system to repro this specific case.  Even if you think it's not special, it's good to be specific.

Comment: added.. both package.json files

Comment: If the final transpiled library code ends up in node_modules, I don't think the Firebase CLI is watching that space for updates.  You could file an issue on GitHub if you'd like for it to behave differently.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I was afraid that was the case.. I opened a ticket.. thank you!

Comment: so apparently they almost do.. I have updated the question..